# Why is the comment cid not being replaced with tokens?

Tags: drupal-7, token

On admin/structure/trigger/comment I have the following:
[image]

On admin/config/system/actions I have the following:
[image]

When I click "configure" and go to admin/config/system/actions/configure/81

[image]

Here's the text in the message textarea:

```
[comment:url:absolute]
Comment ID: <a href="https://example.com/comment/[comment:cid]#comment-[comment:cid]">[comment:cid]</a>

Comment Text:
[comment:body]

Comment Author:
[comment:author]

Comment Created:
[comment:created]
```

This is the email I receive, notice how it is not replacing comment:cid:

```
https://example.com/comment/#comment-
Comment ID:
Comment Text:
This is a test comment.

Comment Author:
auser

Comment Created:
February 5, 2015 - 21:20
```

Comment: Are you sure, you are selecting comments token from given list below?

Comment: Yes, I selected them right from the token thing that pops up